# Are there user-defined-literals for variables?

Tags: c++, c++11, literals, user-defined-literals

The user-defined-literals from C++11 helps the integers and float numbers have certain units like m, cm, mm, km, and so on. But it seems that it deals only with constant.
I have a runtime program which always calculates some lengths and convert them between different units. 
Are there also similar mechanisms like user-defined-literals in C++ for variables?

Comment: Those are called types. You can use a [library](https://github.com/nholthaus/units) if you don't want to write them yourself.

Comment: Are you looking for something like [boost::units](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_65_0/doc/html/boost_units.html)?

Comment: Could you be more precise and share an example?

Comment: The idea of "user-defined-literals...for variables" makes no sense.  The word "literal" means, the in-source-code representation of a particular _value_.  It's practically a synonym for "constant".  I agree with nwp: It sounds like you are asking how to define specialized numeric types.

Answer (score 0):

[To my knowledge, the C++14 standard provides literal operators for complex numbers, string, string_view and std::chrono time values.](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/user_literal). There are no operators defined for other SI units, and there no classes supporting this in the standard.

There are libraries to define unit systems, e.g. Boost.Units. However, as far I read the docs, Boost.Units does not defined user-defined literal operator. But then it should be easy to do it on your own.